# Flex chart timeline

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, taskmanager

(sorry for my english)

Hi, exist in flex a component similar to task manager of windows that shows the performance of the cpu?

I need read data from a wsdl every X seconds and update the chart.

thanks

Comment: Are you referring to a prebuilt CPU meter in flex?  or are you trying to have a line graph similar to a CPU usage history graph, which you can draw arbitrary data to, every time you hit the wsdl?

Comment: I solved my problem using http://www.iwobanas.com/2009/07/scrolling-and-zooming-chart-with-chartscroller/

Comment: Awesome, glad to hear it worked out :)